# why my arraylist doesn't keep the last answer?

Tags: java, arraylist

When I type 1 the ArrayList now has 1 then when I rerun the code and type 2 the `ArrayList` print 2, but what I need is to print 2 and the last answer which is 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer =s.nextInt();
    num.add(answer);
    System.out.println(num);
    System.out.println(num.size());
}
```

Comment: Your list is stored in memory. When your program ends, the list also disappears. Your would have to store it to disk if you want its values to be available when you rerun the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run this program a new ArrayList object is created (a new ArrayList object is empty, obviously). That's why you don't see the inputs from previous runs.

Answer (score 0):

To get the elements that you entered in the run time for another run time you should save the values in a file(secondary storage) and read it when you run the program 
so your code should be like this, at the end of the code write back the new data in the same file

```
ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();

    File file =  new File("file.txt"); 
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){

                MyText+=sc.nextLine();
                num.add(Integer.parseInt(myText))
                 }

    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
int answer =s.nextInt();
num.add(answer);
System.out.println(num);
System.out.println(num.size());
```